# Get Records Not Present in Other Table

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I have two tables:

all_countries

```
╔════╦═════════════╗
║ ID ║   COUNTRY   ║
╠════╬═════════════╣
║  1 ║ USA         ║
║  2 ║ China       ║
║  3 ║ India       ║
║  4 ║ France      ║
║  5 ║ UK          ║
║  6 ║ Australia   ║
║  7 ║ Philippines ║
╚════╩═════════════╝
```

supported_countries

```
╔════════════╦═══════════╦═══════════╗
║ COUNTRY_ID ║  COUNTRY  ║ FILTER_ID ║
╠════════════╬═══════════╬═══════════╣
║          1 ║ USA       ║         1 ║
║          2 ║ China     ║         1 ║
║          3 ║ India     ║         1 ║
║          4 ║ France    ║         2 ║
║          1 ║ USA       ║         2 ║
║          6 ║ Australia ║         2 ║
╚════════════╩═══════════╩═══════════╝
```

Query:

```
SELECT a.* 
FROM all_countries a
LEFT JOIN supported_countries s
  ON a.id = s.country_id
WHERE s.country_id IS NULL;
```

So as per above example I should get.

```
UK
Philippines
```

It works fine, but what if, if I filter the country example I choose to filter = 2.
i get zero result.

```
SELECT a.* 
FROM all_countries a
LEFT JOIN supported_countries s
  ON a.id = s.country_id
WHERE s.filter = 2 AND s.country_id IS NULL;
```

supposed to be i want to get this result, if filter = 2.

```
╔════╦═════════════╗
║ ID ║   COUNTRY   ║
╠════╬═════════════╣
║  2 ║ China       ║
║  3 ║ India       ║
║  5 ║ UK          ║
║  7 ║ Philippines ║
╚════╩═════════════╝
```

Am I doing the correct query?

Answer (score 2):

add the condition on the `ON` clause,

```
SELECT  a.* 
FROM    all_countries a
        LEFT JOIN supported_countries s
           ON a.id = s.country_id AND 
              s.filter_ID = 2        -- <<=== HERE
WHERE   s.country_id IS NULL;
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1102e/2)

Result:

```
╔════╦═════════════╗
║ ID ║   COUNTRY   ║
╠════╬═════════════╣
║  2 ║ China       ║
║  3 ║ India       ║
║  5 ║ UK          ║
║  7 ║ Philippines ║
╚════╩═════════════╝
```

Comment: for faster performance, you need to have indexes on these columns: `a.id`,`s.country_id`,`s.filter_ID`.